# how to pass the value and limit the loop

Tags: php

```
<?php

  $col = 0;
  if ($num_products_count > 0) {
    while (!$specials_index->EOF) {
      $list_box_contents[$row][$col] ='<a>'.$specials_index->fields['products_name']. '</a>';
      $col ++;
    }
  }

?>
```

How do I limit the loop to only five iterations?

When I do the first loop, I want the `$specials_index->fields['products_name']` value to be `<img src="1.jpg">`. the second is `<img src="2.jpg">`, the third is `<img src="3.jpg">`, the fourth is `<img src="4.jpg">`, the fifth is `<img src="5.jpg">`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Comment: Wow! You really show no effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code to limit the loop to 5 iterations :

```
<?php
$col = 0;
if ($num_products_count > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while (!$specials_index->EOF && ($i < 5)) {
        $list_box_contents[$row][$col] ='<a>'.$specials_index->fields['products_name']. '</a>';
        $col++;
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```

as for your second question, it's not clear enough. If you want to generate the `img` tags use the the value of `$i` at each iteration

```
$specials_index->fields['products_name'] = '<img src="'.$i.'">';
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one...

```
  $col = 0;
  if ($num_products_count > 0) {
    while (!$specials_index->EOF) {
      $list_box_contents[$row][$col] ='<a>'.$specials_index->fields['products_name']. '<img src="'.$col+1.'"></a>';
      $col ++;
      if ($col = 5) { break; }
    }
  }
```